# What is the naming convention in Python for asynchronous functions?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, naming-conventions

In python class, when you have to mix synchronous and asynchronous functions, what is the best practice ?

first option:

```
Class My_Class:
  def myfct_sync(...)
  async def myfct_async(...)
```

second option: prefix with a 'a' character, like `__iter__` and `__aiter__`

```
Class My_Class:
  def myfct(...)
  async def amyfct(...)
```

third option: separate in two classes

```
Class My_Class:
  def myfct(...)

Class Async_My_Class:
  async def myfct(...)
```

Comment: [This link](https://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/pep_ideas/async_programming.html#naming-conventions) is worth reading.

Comment: And see also this [django discussion](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/naming-of-async-variants/7216)

Answer (score 0):

All classes in Python should be `PascalCase`. This is detailed in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names). Aside from that, I am not aware of any specific `asyncio` naming conventions.

For asynchronous related classes, it is up to you and your code base. In a purely `asyncio` codebase, I don't think there is any added benefit by putting the word `Async` somewhere in the class names. However, in a code base where `asyncio` code will be mixed in with synchronous code, I think there is indeed a benefit to prefixing classes with `Async`. For example, say that you have a synchronous thread communicating with an `asyncio` event loop. Inside the event loop, you might create an `Inbox` class to communicate between the various coroutines and tasks running on the event loop. It makes sense to name the class `AsyncInbox` instead of just `Inbox` to make it clear that it is intended to be used inside an event loop.

For methods, that is again up to you. If you look at the core module for [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html), there is a mix of synchronous (`get_nowait`, `put_nowait`) and asynchronous methods (`get`, `put`). For the most part, a linter for your IDE such as Pylance should make it clear enough whether a method or function returns a coroutine or not. Also, coroutines are **required** to use the `async` keyword. So generally speaking and as opposed to my recommendation for classes, I think it doesn't make much sense to add the word `async` into a function or method.

Where it does make sense to me is for when a class (and thus methods) or a module (and thus functions) expose two versions of a function, one synchronous and one asynchronous. In such a special case, one could consider putting `_async` as a suffix. But that still depends. For example, the `asyncio.Queue` class above doesn't do that because the `get_nowait` and `put_nowait` are effectively non-blocking functions. If they were, then naming them `get_sync` and `put_sync` OR leaving them as `get` and `put` and naming the asynchronous blocking versions as `get_async` and `put_async` would be some options.